# Can I set PHP to use with utf 8 for Sqlite 3

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to get and dump an Sqlite field using PHP. Because of some characters I can't get specific values. Here's my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM siir WHERE siirAdi_txt LIKE 'Ağustos Şiiri%' COLLATE NOCASE";
```

Does Sqlite 3 support utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

copy paste from site:
SQLite Version 3 Overview

SQLite version 3.0 introduces important changes to the library, including:

```
A more compact format for database files.
Manifest typing and BLOB support.
**Support for both UTF-8 and UTF-16 text.**
User-defined text collating sequences.
64-bit ROWIDs.
Improved Concurrency.
```

Comment: then where am I doing mistake